# Pass Generic SObject List From LWC to Flow

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, flow-screen-component

I am trying to pass SObject list from LWC to flow.

I have set the property and property type.

```
<targetConfigs>
     <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
          <propertyType name="T" extends="SObject" label="Input Type" description="Generic sObject data type used for input sObject properties" />
          <property label="Select SObject" name="recList" role="inputOnly" type="{T[]}" />
     </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```

I have also set the required elements in the flow.

[image]

When I run the debugger , I can see the values in the recList . But it is not being passed to Flow. Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

- Make sure you publish the event to the flow using the `FlowAttributeChangeEvent` event.
- Outputs from an LWC FSC cannot (as of v.53.0) be listened to by other elements on the same page.  The values are only available once you click next.  i.e. Try creating another screen, and output the values there.

**Publishing the event**

See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/use_flow_runtime_considerations

> Lightning web components use events to report changes from components to flows. To notify the flow runtime of attribute changes, a component fires the FlowAttributeChangeEvent event.

Comment: I added the FlowAttributeChangeEvent and added another screen. SCREEN: Bulk Upload CCs
Lightning Component: addCaseContacts
Screen component: c:addCaseContacts
Inputs:
recList = recList (null)
Outputs:
null

Display Text: test1
Value at run time:

recList is null.