# Pass Object or Object Array from LWC to Screen Flow

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, error, bug

I'm trying to send a variable from lwc to a screen flow. But when this variable is a Object or Array of Objects, the flow doesn't recognize and prints a empty value. I don't know what i'm doing wrong or if this is a bug.

**Flow Running on API Version 59**

My LWC code:

lwcFlowTest.js

```js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class LwcFlowTest extends LightningElement {
    @api 
    get stringVariable() {
        return 'Text';
    }

    @api 
    get stringArrayVariable() {
        return ['Text', 'Array'];
    }

    @api 
    get objectVariable() {
        return {
            LastName: 'Lead',
            Company: 'Company Lead'
        }
    }

    @api 
    get objectArrayVariable() {
        return [
            {
                LastName: 'Lead',
                Company: 'Company Lead'
            },
            {
                LastName: 'Lead 2',
                Company: 'Company Lead 2'
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

lwcFlowTest.js-meta.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>58.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>

    <targets>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>

    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property
            name = "stringVariable"
            label= "String Variable"
            role = "outputOnly"
            type = "String"/>

            <property
            name = "stringArrayVariable"
            label= "String Array Variable"
            role = "outputOnly"
            type = "String[]"/>

            <property
            name = "objectVariable"
            label= "Object Variable"
            role = "outputOnly"
            type = "@salesforce/schema/Lead"/>

            <property
            name = "objectArrayVariable"
            label= "Object Array Variable"
            role = "outputOnly"
            type = "@salesforce/schema/Lead[]"/>
        </targetConfig>        
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

the html file its empty just with

And the flow its just 2 screens, in the first the lwc is called, and in the next its printed the values.

[image: Complete Flow]
[image: Flow Screen 1]
[image: Flow Screen 2]

When I run the flow, this is the output from the flow
[image: Output From Flow]

What i'm doing wrong? or pass object or object array from lwc to flow doesn't work?

Comment: Have you checked this? - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/360273/pass-generic-sobject-list-from-lwc-to-flow
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76234653/how-to-pass-selected-records-i-e-list-of-records-which-isnt-related-to-any-sob

Comment: @TusharJadav yes, in my case i'm getting the output after I click next, I don't need this return on the same page. Because of that I don't think that is necessary to make a "FlowAttributeChangeEvent". My case is exactly the second option and don't work when a print the values. For the second link my variable is a getter, you can see on the screenshots this works nicely for String and String[], but not for SObject or SObject[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LWC code is working as expected.

To display Object you will need to indicate its properties like below

```
Lead Last Name: {!lwcFlowTest.ObjectVariable.LastName}
Lead Company Name: {!lwcFlowTest.ObjectVariable.Company}
```

To display Array variable you will need to use probably a Datatable as the the simple Display Text component does not have capability to show it

Check the output below where I used the same code as you

[image]